# Having trouble displaying output

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

This might sound like a simple thing for you programmers out there but i can't seem to figure it out. I'm making a program that where among 4 numbers the largest is outputted. I've got the core code working but i can't seem to think how i can display the results on the screen. I would like it so that when the user types a number into a text box the result appears in another text box at the press of a button. Thanks for your time & help.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="Main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="Awesome">
            <label>Input Numbers Here: </label><input type="text" 
id="txtBox">
            <br><br>
            <label>Dec to Roman #: </label><input type="text" id="Results">
            <br><br>
            <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="Execute" 
onclick="largestOfFour()">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
var largestNumbers = [];
var currentLargest;
for (var x =0; x <arr.length; x++) {
    currentLargest = 0;
    for (var y = 0; y < arr [x].length; y++) {
        if (arr[x][y] > currentLargest) {
            currentLargest = arr[x][y];
        }
    }
    largestNumbers.push(currentLargest);
}
return largestNumbers;

document.getElementById('Results').value = largestNumbers;

}
```

Comment: From where is the largestOfFour function getting the arr input?

Comment: And why is largestNumbers an array, if it's just going to tell the largest number among the other numbers then it should not be an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After entering the numbers in an input box, we can read its value as a string. Splitting that string with a space give us the numbers array. We will compare each number in that array to each other and save the biggest number in `largest`. Then we display its value in a Result box.

```js
function largestOfFour() {
  // get string from the input
  var s = document.getElementById('txtBox').value;
  var numbers = s.split(' ');
  var largest = 0;
  for (var x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
    var current = parseInt(numbers[x])
    if (current > largest)
      largest = current;
  }
  // display the largest number
  document.getElementById('Results').value = largest;
}
```

```html
<form id="Awesome">
  <label>Input 4 Numbers (space separated): </label>
  <input type="text" id="txtBox">
  <br><br>
  <label>Max #: </label>
  <input type="text" id="Results" readonly>
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="Execute" onclick="largestOfFour()">
</form>
```

Comment: Thankyou very much!

Comment: Glad I could help.